# KnotTheory` Passing PD Encoding of a Knot Diagram to Kh

Tags: packages, topology, knots

I have a bunch of knot diagrams I would like to use the `Kh` function in `KnotTheory` to compute the Khovanov homology for. Almost all the examples in the [documentation](http://katlas.org/wiki/Khovanov_Homology) are computations on knots that are stored somewhere in the `KnotTheory` look-up tables.

This is not sufficient for my use-case, I want to pass a knot as encoded in `PD[X[a,b,c,d], … ]` notation to `Kh` and have Mathematica compute its Khovanov homology.

The very last example in the documentation seems to claim one can do this by running `JavaKh` (supposedly the underlying program for the `Kh` command) in the command line outside of Mathematica. I’ve been trying to replicate this within Mathematica for a while now and I haven’t been able to get it to work.

Can `KnotTheory`‘s `Kh` compute Khovanov homology from an arbitrary plane diagram encoding?

Comment: Also for me the docs read as if this was possible at some point in time. I could be wrong, but my impression is that some parts of the package are quite outdated. For example, I have to hack the main `.m` file every time I reinstall it to make it run because the package assumes a very old version of _Mathematica_. So it could well be that `JavaKh` does not work anymore. But apparently, you can select various backends for `Kh` (see `?Kh` for details). Not all of them are as efficient; but at least some of them might still work.

Comment: Also note that you probably have to install the _Java Runtime Environment_ to run `JavaKh`. (But I am not an expert on Java.)

Comment: I chatted with Kyle Miller about this and he found the syntax I needed by looking at the source:  
`Kh[PD[X[1,2,3,4] ... ], Program -> "FastKh"]` 
does exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As gdd mentions in the comments, you can use the Mathematica implementation (rather than one of the Java implementations) by specifying which program to use:

```mathematica
Kh[PD[X[a,b,c,d], ...], Program -> "FastKh"]
```

The [KnotTheory](http://katlas.org/wiki/Khovanov_Homology) documentation suggests that this is thousands of times slower than the Java implementation, but it at least still appears to work.